# Unable to retrieve the value from DB using Liferay Service Builder

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide, liferay-velocity, liferay-aui

I am learning Liferay and have been stuck in a place where I don't know what to do.

I will just brief out what I am doing.

Creating a Library Management System using service builder and have the following Code in Service.xml file.

```xml
<entity name="LMSBook" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
    <!-- PK fields -->
    <column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true" id-type="increment"/>
    <!-- UI fields -->
    <column name="bookTitle" type="String" />
    <column name="author" type="String" />
    <!-- Audit fields -->
    <column name="dateAdded" type="Date" />
</entity>
```

The Service build was successful without any errors. Now I am using following code to display the data from the table.

See the java below code:

```java
List <LMSBook> books = LMSBookLocalServiceUtil.getLMSBooks(0, -1);
if(books.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Empty");
} else {
    //Some Code Here
}
```

Here the books value is always null. I don't know why and DB has 3 rows in it but still its returning null. When I retrieve single value I am able to retrieve but when it come to multiple values it just returning NULL.

I am using following java code for single value retrieval:

```java
LMSBook book = LMSBookLocalServiceUtil.getLMSBook(1);
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in your code part below:

```java
List <LMSBook> books = LMSBookLocalServiceUtil.getLMSBooks(0, -1);
```

It says limit 0 to -1 which is not correct.

In order to get all records you should use below code:

```java
List <LMSBook> books = LMSBookLocalServiceUtil.getLMSBooks(-1, -1);
```

If you use -1 as start and end, it will return all the records.

Comment: Thank u very Much its working Now and i have an alter way as well by get the number of books in DB then Giving that value to the getLMSBook(0,count);